# Tracing with pychrome

Tags: python, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, trace

I am trying to measure number of CPU instructions of my JS code. I am using pychrome but i can't get my performance mark. Although i can get my mark using chrome performance profiling.

My js code:

```
<script>
  performance.mark('my-start');

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      a = Math.cbrt(Math.random() * 100);
      console.log(a);
    }         
  }
  performance.mark('my-end');
  performance.measure('my-benchmark', 'my-start', 'my-end');
</script>
```

Python code:

```
import pychrome
import json

browser = pychrome.Browser(url="http://127.0.0.1:9222")

tab = browser.new_tab()
open('data.json', 'w').close()

def tracing_complete(**kwargs):
    eof = False
    while not eof:
        data = tab.call_method("IO.read", handle=kwargs["stream"])
        eof = data["eof"]
        print(eof)
        if data["data"]:
            data = json.loads(str(data["data"]))
            with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
                json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

    tab.call_method("IO.close", handle=kwargs["stream"])

tab.set_listener("Tracing.tracingComplete", tracing_complete)

tab.start()
tab.call_method("Network.enable")

tab.call_method("Tracing.start", transferMode='ReturnAsStream', _timeout=5)
tab.call_method("Page.navigate", url="my_page.html", _timeout=5)
tab.call_method("Tracing.end",  _timeout=5)

tab.wait(5)
tab.stop()
browser.close_tab(tab)
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: No. I am able to get all data from stream but it looks like i'm getting either wrong data or data incomplete

Comment: How do you say so?

Comment: I compared log that I get from chrome performance profiling and my log

Comment: Please post that if you can. It might help

Comment: I uploaded files to google drive.
Log from chrome:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T1nuwiqWymgXOyDSWZEuJrIPXN25Kbf9/view?usp=sharing

My log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bIfn3I4R6bSsiTlfsfw0YC0PNx9SEEui/view?usp=sharing

Comment: These logs are preety big but you could find my marks in log from chrome